# useEffect update only when some fields in states have been changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Suppose that I have the following state

```
const [states, setStates] = useState([
      {name: '', age: '', amount: ''},
      {name: '', age: '', amount: ''},
]);
const total = 0;
```

I wish to use `useEffect` to update **only** when `age` fields are changed to calculate the `amount` fields. And then update the `total` field based on the `amount` fields changed. How do I do that? In this example, I have small number of array with three fields, but in reality, I have a big array with a lot of fields, so I don't want to use `useEffect` when any fields in `states` change.

Comment: `amount` can be a computed filed on render time. If the computation is expensive you can do memoization, you can write your own Memoization or use useMemo hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you **can't** do that - the `useEffect` hook doesn't provide the ability to keep track of specific object properties inside of an array.

You'd have to keep track of another piece of state that will change if any of the `age` properties change, which will trigger the `useEffect` that has that piece of state in the dependency array.

```js
const [states, setStates] = React.useState([...])
const [lastAgeUpdatedAt, setLastAgeUpdatedAt] = React.useState(null)
// const total = 0; // by the way, this looks like something that 
                    // should also be stored in a state,
                    // the below would be more appropriate
const [total, setTotal] = React.useState(0)

const handleUpdateAge = () => {
  setStates(...)
  if (ageUpdatesAvailable) {
    setLastAgeUpdatedAt(Date.now())
  }
}


React.useEffect(() => {
  const total = states.reduce(
    (accumulator, item) => accumulator + parseInt(item.age, 10), 
    0
  )
  setTotal(total)
}, [lastAgeUpdatedAt])
```

Comment: Do you think that this can work with `ref`? Basically, as soon as the user focuses it an input, select that as ref and use that in `useEffect` with `[ref]` as dependencies?

Comment: I suggest not using `ref`s in ways that they're not meant to be used. Why not just keep a track of when an `age` property was last updated?

Comment: @Raza note about `refs` from the doc - https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs

Comment: I thought `ref` was a perfect use case for that.

Comment: @Raza not according to the docs and not the way you're proposing it with the `useEffect` hook.